# Remove just added volume from LVM

Tags: lvm

We did the following:

1. Added a volume (500G) to the volume group
2. Extended the logical volume on the volume group

We did not extend the filesystem on the logical volume.

Then we decided, that it is not a good idea.

Now we want to safely remove the volume again.

The plan:

1. `lvreduce` the logical volume exactly to the file system
2. vgreduce

Questions:

1. How to exactly find out the size of the file system?
2. Does LVM automatically detect, that the space provided by the new phyiscal volume is no longer used and allows unplugging of the volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian seems to create backups of the vg configuration at `/etc/lvm/archive` - it should be possible to use such an old config.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have backups.

Hardest part is determining the exact size of your old filesystem. Either you have and can use the `--resizefs` option to lvreduce/lvresize in which case you can use lvreduce safely, or else reduce the filesystem first to something **less** than what you will give to lvreduce. That's assuming the FS isn't already full! `dumpe2fs -h $FSMOUNTPOINT | grep '^Block '` will give a block count and size, but I wouldn't rely on it. resize2fs will however accept a target size, that you can then give to lvreduce.

After you have reduced your lv to something that will fit on the disks you want to keep, `pvs` will tell you if your volume is used. If it is, use `pvmove $BADDEVICE $KEEPDEVICE` to make it unused, and then you can use `vgreduce $VG $BADDEVICE` to remove the device from the VG.